# npm install Failed at the @angular/cli@9.1.3 postinstall script

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I'm just starting out, I need to set up a source code on my machine.

> node -v
>   v12.16.1
>   npm -v
>   6.13.4

can you help me resolve this error when I run the `npm install` command ( on Windows 7 Entreprise SP1 64-bit)

```
4400 verbose stack Error: @angular/cli@9.1.3 postinstall: `node 
./bin/postinstall/script.js`
4400 verbose stack Exit status 1
4400 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program 
Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
4400 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:311:20)
4400 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program 
Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
4400 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:311:20)
4400 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
4400 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit 
(internal/child_process.js:286:5)
4401 verbose pkgid @angular/cli@9.1.3
4402 verbose cwd D:\banbou_source\workspace\banbou-project\banbou-backoffice- 
client
4403 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
4404 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program 
Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
4405 verbose node v12.16.1
4406 verbose npm  v6.13.4
4407 error code ELIFECYCLE
4408 error errno 1
4409 error @angular/cli@9.1.3 postinstall: `node ./bin/postinstall/script.js`
4409 error Exit status 1
4410 error Failed at the @angular/cli@9.1.3 postinstall script.
4410 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely 
additional 
logging output above.
4411 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all the problem solved following the addition of the --force option

npm i -g @angular/cli --force

Answer (score 1):

ou must check whether any previous version on Agnular is installed (or even partially) on your computer. If so, then run command:

```
npm uinstall @angular/cli
```

Then clean the npm cache by this command: `npm cache clean --force`

Now, try to re-install Angular by the command: `npm i -g @angular/cli`
The current version of Angular is `9.1.3` so you don't need write it in the command.

Here `-g` command is used to install Angular globally.

For everything to work fine, please close all IDE (if being used) then perform above oprations.

Comment: i got this error:                                                                                                                   
 npm ERR! Cannot read property 'match' of undefined

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

Comment: trying npm i -g @angular/cli --force : it seems to work better: Error read EINVAL
←[90m    at TTY.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:201:27)←[39m
Emitted 'error' event on ReadStream instance at:
←[90m    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)←[39m
←[90m    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)←[39m
←[90m    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)←[3
9m {
  errno: ←[32m'EINVAL'←[39m,
  code: ←[32m'EINVAL'←[39m,
  syscall: ←[32m'read'←[39m
}
+ @angular/cli@9.1.6
added 271 packages from 206 contributors in 31.457s

Comment: If your are using Windows, try running the node command terminal as administrator. For this press Windows button then search fro ```node``` then node command terminal will show. Right click on that and run as administrator. After the terminal window opens. Try running your command there. Let me know, if you still face any problem.

Comment: I haven't admin rights on my PC, I have to tell the IT department each time, the problem solved following the addition of the --force option. your advice was helpful thanks for All

Answer (score 1):

Try installing angular-cli with --unsafe-perm flag. In Windows, it might be permission issue while installing postinstall.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which of these did the trick or if it was a combination, but this worked for me after trying so many other answers.

I opened a command prompt as administrator in Windows, and I ran the following command.

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@8.0.0 --unsafe-perm --force
```